# IIS6 installing an ssl certificate for the first time.

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, iis-6

This will be my first time (and hopefully last) that I install an ssl cert on iis6.

We have multiple different root domain sites hosted on this server, each with its own IP Address.

If I install a cert for say,  example.com on IP Address 1, what will happen if a user tries to navigate to otherexample.org on IP Address 2 over https? Will the connection be refused,  or will they be served the only certificate installed?

Answer (score 0):

This is the thing about certificates. Everything about certificates must be correct and must match. Or there will be an error and it will not work. There are some exceptions - a wildcard certificate can match multiple names for a given domain name, but that is about it.

So no, connections to otherexample.org will fail.  And I am ignoring that the other IP address is not bound to any certificate.

Comment: I don't understand.  So even if ip address number 2 is not configured to use a certificate,  connections will still fail?

Comment: That's the concept. When you configure a certificate in IIS, you are usually binding that certificate to a specific IP address/name.